# codeigniter base url and routes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to develop my codeigniter (v3) application at this address:

```
http://localhost/mycodeigniterApp/
```

I have :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycodeigniterApp/';
```

I get a 404 when I try to load any address in my applicaiton ( except for the default ).

Comment: Couple checks make sure you class and file name of controller has first letter upper case. Then check your routes.php

Comment: try loading http://localhost/mycodeigniterApp/index.php/your controller/function

Comment: can you sent your tried url path

Comment: http://localhost/mycodeigniterApp/index.php/yourController @GRY

Comment: Indeed, it was the absence of the index.php in the URL.  If someone makes this the answer, I'll mark it true. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing this up the correct response was:

> Couple checks make sure you class and file name of controller has
>   first letter upper case. Then check your routes.php